# How to disable an Input tag in React by assigning a state to an Input tag

Tags: reactjs, ant-design-pro

I am working with React and for designing I am using Ant design, My question is I have a Form in that form I have three Input tags. According to Ant design I know how to disable a Button or Input tag, But here I am trying to disable an Input tag through state but it's not working. So someone please help me to achieve this.

This is What I tried -- App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import { Form, Input, Button } from 'antd'
import "./App.css";

const App = () => {
  const [disableUsername, setDisableUsername] = useState(disable)
  return (
    <div style={{marginTop: "100px"}}>
      <Form
      name="basic"
      labelCol={{
        span: 6,
      }}
      wrapperCol={{
        span: 6,
      }}
      initialValues={{
        remember: true,
      }}
    >
      <Form.Item
        label="Username"
        name="username"
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: 'Please input your username!',
          },
        ]}
      >
        {disableUsername &&
        <Input />
}
      </Form.Item>

      <Form.Item
        label="Email"
        name="email"
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: 'Please input your email!',
          },
        ]}
      >
        <Input disabled />
      </Form.Item>

      <Form.Item
        label="Password"
        name="password"
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: 'Please input your password!',
          },
        ]}
      >
        <Input.Password />
      </Form.Item>

      <Form.Item
        wrapperCol={{
          offset: 8,
          span: 16,
        }}
      >
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to pass true/false to the disabled attribute of Input component. If disableUsername contains a boolean state, then you can use it for toggling.

```
<Input
    // This is where you want to disable your UI control
    disabled={disableUsername}
    placeholder="Username"
/>
```